# accurate runtime calculation in C

Tags: c, linux, runtime

I am trying to calculate the runtime of an algorithm in linux C. I am using `clock_t` struct to calculate the runtime as follows:

```
clock_t t,start,

start=clock();

//code

t=clock()-start;
printf("Time Taken=%f msec\n",(((double)t/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000.00);
```

The problem is I am not getting the runtime as expected (it is much less than expected). Moreover, the runtime is always in a multiple of `10` which is pretty abnormal. Also it keeps varying by a large factor. Is there any accurate method in C to calculate the runtime?

Comment: AFAIK you can't if you're running the program on a multitasking OS. Those changes are because of the OS switching processes.

Comment: `clock` doesn't give you the run time but the processor time that your process used

Comment: Just curious: what is the measurement variance you're getting?

Comment: One obvious thing that is commonly done in cases like these is to run the test *many* times, so that any measurement error and/or quantization that is happening is amortized over all the runs. This makes it possible to get an accurate per-test reading, but of course takes more time.

Comment: Well, I am measuring the time just to write an image buffer to SD card. The time varies from 20 msec to 70 msec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux the most accurate timers are generally

- clock_gettime with CLOCK_MONOTONIC, this measures wallclock with nanosecond resolution if you have a new enough kernel.
- getrusage, measures CPU cycles spent by a process, IIRC at a frequency determined by the kernel tick frequency (jiffies), thus typically 1-10 ms resolution. This is in practice what you'll get with clock() as well, except getrusage gets you the time broken down into user+sys components, you can specify whether you want child time included etc.
- As jpalecek mentions, clock_gettime with CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID should give you high-resolution process time, (though I've never used it myself).

Comment: clock_gettime() does the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

clock() is pretty imprecise, what you describe says it "ticks" every 10 ms. You can try using [`clock_gettime` with the accompanying function `clock_getres` with the `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` timer](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime).

Also, you might want to calculate the wall-clock time (that includes waiting etc., as opposed to cpu-clock time) with `gettimeofday()`. That is more precise, too.

Answer (score 0):

use this function.Thsi will calculate teh time difference in microseconds.

```
int timeval_subtract ( struct timeval *result,  struct timeval *x,  struct timeval *y)
{
  /* Perform the carry for the later subtraction by updating y. */
  if (x->tv_usec < y->tv_usec) {
    int nsec = (y->tv_usec - x->tv_usec) / 1000000 + 1;
    y->tv_usec -= 1000000 * nsec;
    y->tv_sec += nsec;
  }
  if (x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec > 1000000) {
    int nsec = (x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec) / 1000000;
    y->tv_usec += 1000000 * nsec;
    y->tv_sec -= nsec;
  }

  /* Compute the time remaining to wait.
     tv_usec is certainly positive. */
  result->tv_sec = x->tv_sec - y->tv_sec;
  result->tv_usec = x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec;

  /* Return 1 if result is negative. */
  return x->tv_sec < y->tv_sec;
}
```

how to use it:

```
struct timeval starttime,endtime,timediff;
gettimeofday(&starttime,0x0);
//your code 
..
..
//your code ends
gettimeofday(&endtime,0x0);
timeval_subtract(&timediff,&endtime,&starttime);
```

`timediff.tv_sec` will the seconds.
`timediff.tv_usec`  will be the microseconds.

so total time diff is `timediff.tv_sec.timediff.tv_usec`

Comment: Or, since the question is tagged "linux", just use timersub(), if the problem is "how do I subtract two struct timeval objects".